# Cleaning facebook url cache from php

Tags: php, facebook, caching, curl

I have an issue with the facebook linter feature. I'm trying to clean the Facebook cache of one my URL, with a PHP curl query. As you can see [here (Updating Objects)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-update), Facebook got an api for scrapping all the content of an URL and update URL Facebook meta. It's the same API used in the [Facebook Debugger Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

If I use their debugger manually, there is no problem. My URL is correctly scrapped and all corrects meta are retrieved. But it's not the case with a php curl query.

Here my actual code :

```
$furl = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $furl );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
$params = array(
    'id' => "http://www.gametrader-app.com/aTPVev",
    'scrape' => true,
 );
$data = http_build_query( $params );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$resultLinter = curl_exec( $ch );
```

The API result displays incorrect/old facebook meta.

Moreover, I have tried to call directly the URL of the Debugger without success

```
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_URL, "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.example.com");
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_HEADER , 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , $useragent );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$str_response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

I need to do this for one reason. Here the full process :

1. Publish a new ad on the iPhone App "GameTrader"
2. Post an open graph on facebook for this publish
3. That's all ;)

If I don't clean the URL cache on Facebook side before the post open graph, I get this error :

```
Error during open graph : OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL 
http://www.gametrader-app.com/aTPVev has og:type of 'website'. The property 'ad' requires an object of og:type 'gametrader-app:ad'
```

Can you help to understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Cheers!

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You need to change the `og:type` in your metadata to `gametrader-app:ad`, instead of `website`.

Comment: The og:type is gametrader-app:ad. But Facebook seems to have a cache for these URL, and save it with website og:type